# How can i turn off the android emulator by using code in eclipse?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is it possible to turn off the android emulator by using code in eclipse?
And if yes,how can i turn it on again.
In all the answers i found on the internet,the emulator was turned off by the command line,but i need to control it from eclipse.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: @Simon I'm making an application that turns off your phone if your sim card is changed

Comment: When you say "control it from eclipse" do you mean the android application that is running on the emulator? Or do you mean a different project in eclipse?

Comment: @Paperwaste I mean that i need to be able to turn the emulator on or off by writing a code in eclipse. When the sim card is changed,the app detects it and then it should turn off the emulator (or phone).

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically reboot an android device using the following

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
pm.reboot("your reason")
```

This requires the REBOOT permission in the manifest.

Comment: This might solve it indirectly. If there weren't any direct solutions i'll do it like that. Thank you!